# Replace urls in string with a condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert urls in a string to a link with a condition that the url must be same as the domain I'm using. How do I do this?

My domain is http://www.domain.com

```
str = "This is a www.domain.com text with url. This is another url: www.domain2.com. This is a part of a url: http://domain.com/foo.php. This is another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. Another link: domain.com/bar.php";
```

What I want is:

1. www.domain.com to be changed to `<a href='www.domain.com'>domain.com</a>`
2. www.domain2.com to stay unchanged.
3. http://domain.com/foo.php to be changed to `<a href='http://domain.com/foo.php'>/foo.php</a>`.
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask to stay unchanged.
5. domain.com/bar.php to be changed to `<a href='domain.com/bar.php'>/bar.php</a>`

How can I do this with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do it:

```
str.replace(/(?:(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(domain\.com))(\/[a-zA-Z]+\.php)?/g,
    function(a,b,c) {
        return '<a href="'+a+'">'+(c ? c : b)+'</a>';
    });
```

Here's working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/URLzx/1/.